# I need to update a file with a column from a previous row of data using SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql

I have identified the rows of data that I want to work with using a CTE and I am trying to update my current record with a field from the previous record. I am using `row_number` and partitions to get the data into related groups. When I execute the code I have written, every record is updated with the exact same date rather than the date that corresponds to the grouping I defined within my partition.

```
WITH numbered AS (
  SELECT mfg , serialno1 , datenxt, rowno = row_number()  
      OVER (PARTITION BY mfg, serialno1 ORDER BY datenxt )     
  FROM   eqhist
)
update dbo.eqhist
set offrdt=b.datenxt
from numbered a
 left JOIN numbered b 
   ON a.mfg=b.mfg and a.serialno1=b.serialno1 and b.rowno = a.rowno - 1
```

What step am I missing?

Comment: I would run the "update step" as a select with offrdt and datenxt and rows, etc. just to confirm that it looks right there, i.e. the values you intend using.

Comment: Somewhere along the lines you have to join eqhist to your derived table.

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS WAY.

SELECT MFG,SCN,DT1,DT2,RN=ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MFG,SCN,DT1,DT2) INTO #RCTE FROM RCTE
SELECT * INTO #RCTE2 FROM #RCTE
UPDATE #RCTE SET DT2=#RCTE2.DT1 FROM #RCTE INNER JOIN #RCTE2 ON (#RCTE.RN=#RCTE2.RN+1)
SELECT * FROM #RCTE
DROP TABLE #RCTE
DROP TABLE #RCTE2